Wiring 100 Amp panel from service panel
Background information:
I have a 200 AMP service at the socket coming from the pole. I have a 30 amp camper outlet and a 20 amp regular outlet connected to this at the service board. There is also a ground rod installed at this point. An electrician did this.
I have 1 1/2" conduit off that to my structure ~200 feet going to a 100 AMP panel. The wire my electrician told me to use for this is 2-2-2-4 URD aluminum wire. I have it pulled and the conduit all closed off into the 100 amp panel. The panel is a square D Homline 100 AMP 24-space, 48 circuit indoor Main (Home depot-HOM2448M100PCVP)
I know I need to install an additional ground rod at the 100 amp panel as well, and should be all set figuring that out.
Questions:

I can wire this myself with a little guidance because there is a shutoff at the service panel. There are two main lugs on the service panel, I think these are for the right and left hot leg, but want to make sure where the two hot legs, neutral and ground connect to the service panel.

how do I wire it in on the 100 Amp panel in the structure? I have an idea, but want some expertise on this to way in.


I would appreciate it if someone would draw over my picture where to connect things or just tell me, and I will repost the picture with the wiring schematic to make sure. 
panels with wiring: does this look right??

Below is a picture of the unused lugs on the service panel top left of the box. I think these are for the neutral and ground, but not 100% positive. Has anyone worked with this service panel?

I admit this one can be confusing. I've labeled the parts of your panel. The neutral is distributed in this so you can use plug-on-neutral breakers if you want a AFCI breaker.

As you bought a main panel, and not a subpanel, you'll need to buy two small grounding bars (like this bar) and a main lug adapter. It does not matter which side is used where (I would mount the main lug on the right for ease). This answer shows what the one with the lug looks like.
You must have a dedicated ground for this panel. All subpanels are required, by code, to be grounded to the main panel. You said you have 2-2-2-4, so the 4 gauge will be used for your ground. It does not matter which hot goes where on the subpanel, just don't wire one to the neutral by mistake
If this is a freestanding structure, you also need a grounding rod bonded to the ground of the box.
As to the main panel, you will hook your two hots to the 100A breaker. Now for the confusing part: you need to hook both the neutral AND ground to the grounding bar. Note how you have white and green wires on the same bus bar. On the main panel only these are the same thing. Your electrician has hooked them to the utility neutral and run a bare wire (should hook to a grounding rod).

Thank you, that is very helpful. I remade my drawing with wiring so you could confirm it for me. I guess the only question is I don't think the 4 AWG neutral will fit in the bus bar in the main panel. is that were it goes? I will post the new picture in the question.

@hiker Sorry if my diagram is a bit wonky. See the screw ports above the "hot" labels? Those are your "lugs". That's where the hot wires go. It's a giant metal circle with a screw to tension the wire in. You nailed where the neutral goes and these will be the same. However, your subpanel must be under a breaker. That's where your hots go. As for the neutral, if there's no place to tie your ground and neutral to, they do make adapters

ok, i think that maks sense to me. There are two lugs, one bigger in the top left corner of the main service panel. would this be for the neutral? I see what you mean by the adapters though. I will go get the brand and part number of the main to see if I can find more information on it. I would just have the electrician do it, but he is not calling me back. I think he it upset I did not pay him to pull the wire and mount the panel in my yurt, but I saved a lot of money doing that myself.

That 100A panel is sold as a main panel. There is zero reason to expect it came with accessory ground bars. They need to be purchased separately.

The part number the OP gave is for a main-breaker panel. Their photo is of a main-breaker panel. Their text says "100A ... main breaker ... load center". It would not have included accessory ground bars in the box.

@nobody That's true. I stand corrected

This should all basically be fine. Except for one key thing: 2 AWG aluminum is only rated for 90A. If your entire service was 100A then it would actually be OK for reasons. But when using only part of your service you have to go by the standard ampacity calculations in the 75 C column.
The related question is: Is 90A enough? For that you need to do a Load Calculation of the new building. This is not "add up breaker handles" (too high) and not "based on average expected total usage" (because that doesn't account for peaks). There is a specific NEC-compliant way of doing Load Calculations, and that is important here. 90A may be plenty, it might not.

2AWG may be sufficient for his needs considering he's feeding what looks to be a whole dwelling unit with this feeder, not part of one
